# which method calls on press of application icon on home screen when that application is running in background in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

does any one knows which method calls on  pressing of  application icon present on  home screen when that application is running in background in blackberry?

I want to write code for page refreshment their? Does any one have idea please tell me?

Comment: are you showing two icon for your app one for GUi and the other for the background app

Comment: ok then i am assuming that the icon is for gui app so, when you will click on that it will call the class which is extending `UiApplication`

Comment: what you got when you are clicking on the icon can you see your screen on clicking it

Comment: Yes you are right ,but i want to know when application is running in background which method will invoke it?

Comment: yes i saw my application main screen by clicking on that icon.but problem is that when application is not running in background and i click icon it starts app with splash screen and when i click on icon when application is in background it directly shows application main screen(with out showing splash).so that time which method call????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely [UiApplication.activate()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.7.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/UiApplication.html#activate%28%29) is what are looking for. The API says:

> The system invokes this method when it brings this application to the foreground. By default, this method does nothing. Override this method to perform additional processing when being brought to the foreground.

Comment: Arhimed yes your are right.I found that method and it works for me.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Alternate entry point then 
check that in your main method like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 if(args.length>0&&"alternate".equals(args[0])){

    //call Background process here                  

        }

     else{
        // call your gui application here 
     }
}
```

Comment: Uttam i want to refresh my application thats why i am asking.

Comment: Code is too big uttam.i can't put here ,just give me idea how to refresh page content